# Background Tasks are not working

Tags: c#, uwp, background-process

I am not quite sure if this has been asked before but I have searched google but nothing much came up with this problem. I have 2 apps which are submitted to store and they both have almost same background tasks, specifically 2 tasks each.

I register the background tasks, when the app starts and if the app gets updated I check the app version and do things appropriately as described in Microsoft Documentation for UWP apps for Out-of-Process Background Tasks.

The background tasks were working fine before but for a number of days till now, I didn't see any activity regarding background tasks in my system. I checked the event viewer and I saw that according to the triggers defined in the apps the background tasks do "try to start" but there is some problem with the system when the Tasks get killed with exceptions and never actually run.

Please note that while Debugging I can surely run the background Tasks without any problems, the tasks don't run when they start on their own.

Following are the screenshots for event viewer latest logs:

Task 1 for WFW Movies & TV
[image: Task 1 for App - WFW Movies & TV]

Task 2 for WFW Movies & TV
[image: Task 2 for App - WFW Movies & TV]

Task 1 for Anime Deed
[image: Task 1 for App - Anime Deed]

Task 2 for Anime Deed
[image: Task 2 for App - Anime Deed]

The code I use for registration for tasks:

```
private static async void BackgroundTasksRegistrationProcedure()
    {
        string curVer = DataHelper.GetAppVersion();
        TimeTrigger timeTrigger = new TimeTrigger(15, false);
        SystemCondition internetCondition = new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable);
        bool doRegister = false;
        var status1 = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
        switch (status1)
        {
            case BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedByUser:
                {
                    doRegister = false;
                    break;
                }

            case BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedSubjectToSystemPolicy:
                {
                    doRegister = true;
                    break;
                }

            case BackgroundAccessStatus.AlwaysAllowed:
                {
                    doRegister = true;
                    break;
                }

            default:
                break;
        }
        var versionKey = "app_version";
        if (!DataHelper.LocalDataContainer.Values.ContainsKey(versionKey))
        {
            DataHelper.LocalDataContainer.Values[versionKey] = curVer;
            // run tasks registration here
            if (doRegister)
            {
                RegisterBackgroundTask(EpisodeUpdateTaskEntryPoint, EpisodeUpdateTaskName, new TimeTrigger(120, false), internetCondition);
                RegisterBackgroundTask(TileUpdateTaskEntryPoint, TileUpdateTaskName, timeTrigger, internetCondition);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // compare app version
            if (DataHelper.LocalDataContainer.Values[versionKey].ToString() == curVer)
            {
                // run tasks registration here
                if (doRegister)
                {
                    RegisterBackgroundTask(EpisodeUpdateTaskEntryPoint, EpisodeUpdateTaskName, new TimeTrigger(120, false), internetCondition);
                    RegisterBackgroundTask(TileUpdateTaskEntryPoint, TileUpdateTaskName, timeTrigger, internetCondition);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DataHelper.LocalDataContainer.Values[versionKey] = curVer;
                // remove task registrations
                BackgroundExecutionManager.RemoveAccess();
                // run tasks registrations
                await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
                if (doRegister)
                {
                    RegisterBackgroundTask(EpisodeUpdateTaskEntryPoint, EpisodeUpdateTaskName, new TimeTrigger(120, false), internetCondition);
                    RegisterBackgroundTask(TileUpdateTaskEntryPoint, TileUpdateTaskName, timeTrigger, internetCondition);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static BackgroundTaskRegistration RegisterBackgroundTask(string taskEntryPoint, string name, IBackgroundTrigger trigger, IBackgroundCondition condition)
    {
        // We'll add code to this function in subsequent steps.
        foreach (var cur in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        {
            if (cur.Value.Name == name)
            {
                //
                // The task is already registered.
                //
                return (BackgroundTaskRegistration)(cur.Value);
            }
        }
        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder()
        {
            Name = name
        };
        // in-process background tasks don't set TaskEntryPoint
        if (taskEntryPoint != null && taskEntryPoint != string.Empty)
        {
            builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
        }
        builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
        if (condition != null)
        {
            builder.AddCondition(condition);
        }
        BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
        return task;
    }
```

Please help me understand why this is happening. I can Debug the tasks successfully but they don't run on their own when the app is not running. Thanks

**Update:**

I have found another error relating to `BackgroundTaskHost.exe`

```
Faulting application name: backgroundTaskHost.exe, version: 10.0.15063.0, time stamp: 0x9ad06afb
Faulting module name: CoreCLR.dll, version: 4.6.25129.1, time stamp: 0x58dc3e7d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0014101d
Faulting process ID: 0x18bc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2d953c94d6e41
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\syswow64\backgroundTaskHost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1_1.1.25129.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\CoreCLR.dll
Report ID: 8a3a3035-d95b-49bb-a106-d645c604c39b
Faulting package full name: 51918AhmarAftab.WFWMoviesTV_1.3.442.0_x86__rm40d0p5knk1c
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

I think it's a windows issue considering the fault is in `.Net.CoreRuntime`.

Comment: Did you mean the background tasks can work for several days and suddenly come to not work and then never work again?  Could you please find the operational log as the event log mentioned? Did your device keep connect to the internet?  If conveniently, please try to  remove the ` internetCondition` and then testing for days again to see if it still can reproduce.

Comment: I removed the internet condition but still the problem persists and I found some more information and updated the question accordingly.